# PHP - how to access property of object

Tags: php, object

How to access object property starting with @ ? I have got following object stored in **$obj** variable.

```
 Object
(
    [@example] => Array
        (
            [0] => 35815256
            [1] => 38755256 
            [2] => 87678676
        )
    [example] => Array
        (
            [0] => abcdefg
            [1] => abcdef
            [2] => abcde
        )

)
```

**Following print does not work. ERROR: Expected : field name.**

```
print_r($obj -> @example);
```

**This work.**

```
print_r($obj -> example);
```

Comment: Try `$obj->{'@example'}`

Comment: doesnt work, no errors, but got empty object